# Font Awesome working locally, but not on Heroku

Tags: heroku, font-awesome

So I Installed the font-awesome gem and everything looks good, using the latest version etc.
Also included in my application.css:

```
*= require font awesome
```

When I view from local it turns out fine and the glyph-icons show up. When I upload it to heroku, the icons do not show up. I originally had the block squares show up but managed to fix it as I had some messy code in my stylesheets.

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: sorry if this seems silly, but did you make sure that the font-awesome gem is listed as a requirement in your project's Gemfile? It sounds like heroku can't find the gem for some reason, and the most obvious reason I can think of would be that it is missing in the Gemfile

Comment: @Moritz I made sure that the gem is listed. Precompiled and everything before deploying also. I think it is something to do with the asset pipeline but I can't figure out where I have gone wrong with it because everything "looks" ok. gonna dig a little deeper today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue and resolved it (in Rails 4) using info from the following two sources: [Rails Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline) and [Rails Asset Pipeline for Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline)

"With the asset pipeline, the preferred location for these assets is now the app/assets directory". Move the `fonts` folder for font-awesome into `app/assets` and the font awesome js and css files into `vendor/assets` or `app/assets` appropriate javascripts and stylesheets folders.

Now you need to compile the assets for production, run:

```
$ rake assets:precompile
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
$ git add public/assets
$ git commit -m "vendor compiled assets"
```

Then push to heroku

```
$ git push heroku master
```

Hopefully this helps someone else who stumbles upon this question.