# Rails 4: Font Awesome working locally, breaking on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, deployment, font-awesome

Before anything, let me state that I did some research and found the following questions on Stack Overflow about the same issue:

- [rails app not finding fontawesome icons on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868705/rails-app-not-finding-fontawesome-icons-on-heroku)
- [Font Awesome working locally, but not on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472458/font-awesome-working-locally-but-not-on-heroku)

None of the answers above actually help me solve my problem, because they refer to a different setup of Font Awesome.

Indeed, I installed Font Awesome on my Rails 4 with the font-awesome-rails gem, following [the guidelines available here](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails), ie:

- Add `gem "font-awesome-rails"` to my `Gemfile`.
- Run `bundle install`
- Add `*= require font-awesome` to `application.scss`.

Because of this setup, the first SO question mentioned above does not help me, since it refers to the CDN installation of Font Awesome.

In the second question, the valid answer suggests to:

> Move the `fonts` folder for font-awesome into `app/assets` and the font
>   awesome js and css files into `vendor/assets` or `app/assets` appropriate
>   javascripts and stylesheets folders.

But I can't find any `font` folder, nor any font awesome js and css files in my app currently.

—————

**EDIT**: I am happy to delete my question if it is an actual duplicate of any of the questions mentioned above because I just did not understand the given answers.

—————

Is there a specifc way to fix my problem with my current setup?

Comment: Did you try to precompile your assets? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#compiling-assets-locally

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I did and it did not fix my problem. But the solution above did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this command:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

now, run `git add -A`, `git commit` and push to heroku.